# get data from client with regional language in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

client side data sample as below

```
{name:'ABC',age:24,language:'ಕನ್ನಡ'}
```

i need to send language value to another service
but in node console cannot print as above
instead of ಕನ್ನಡ it prints like  `{name:'ABC',age:24,language:'����ͷ�'}`
my express setup like

```
    var express = require('express');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var app = express();

    app.use(bodyParser.json({
            limit: '2mb'
        }));
        app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
            limit: '900kb',
            extended: true
        }));
    app.use((req, res, next) => {
    req.header("Content-Type",  "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    next();
});
```

this is indian kannada language.I try with locale module but no luck.
 how to set accept-language please help me to solve

Answer (score 0):

Use req.headers["accept-language"] to get the language the user has set in his browser.

For easier support look into a [locale module](https://github.com/florrain/locale).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this will help you or not but I just gave it a try:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json({
    limit: '2mb'
}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    limit: '900kb',
    extended: true
}));
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log(decodeURIComponent(req.body.data));
    req.header("Content-Type",  "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    next();
});

app.listen(3000);
```

before posting it:

```
encodeURIComponent('ಕನ್ನಡ'); // returns %E0%B2%95%E0%B2%A8%E0%B3%8D%E0%B2%A8%E0%B2%A1
```

then try:

```
curl -d "data=%E0%B2%95%E0%B2%A8%E0%B3%8D%E0%B2%A8%E0%B2%A1" http://localhost:3000/
```

it will print on console:

> ಕನ್ನಡ

**P.S.** As I mentioned this is just one possible way so there might be other ways as well.